# Let f(n) be the number of n step paths from w to itself on the directed graph below. What is f(12)?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm stumped on a combinatorics problem and I'd just like some help starting out! The question I have is:
Let f(n) be the number of n step paths from w to itself on the directed graph below. What is f(12)?
I have no clue where to start, so any guidance would be greatly helpful.

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: It is $\sum_{2k+3\ell=n}\binom{k+\ell}{k}$

Comment: I'd recommend starting with finding $f(1)$, $f(2)$, etc to get a feel for the problem. Do you know how to find $f$ of any value?

Comment: Combine both of the comments above with the answer of Brian M Scott.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: There are two loops, one of length $2$ and one of length $3$. You can take the longer one $0,2$, or $4$ times, but not once or $3$ times. (Why?) The only case that requires a bit more work is the second one: you take the longer loop twice. How many times must you then take the shorter loop? In how many different orders can you go round the loops?

If you will eventually have to come up with more results about the function $f$, it would be a good idea to work out $f(n)$ for $n\le 12$ using similar ideas. By then you should have a much better idea of how it behaves in general.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it and it was a lot simpler than I expected

Comment: @ninjagirl: You’re very welcome.